# How do I embed openads (Openx) ads in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, openx

I have tried using iframe, javascript and image tag Ad tags in iPhone application, but none of them work. When a user clicks on an image, the browser is launched but then nothing happens (you get a blank page). Anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To proceed: debug it. A standard OpenX click URL will do a redirect. What URL is the browser sticking at?

I don't know anything about iPhone applications, but I do know about interfacing to OpenX. You possible should consider using the OpenX API, which will allow you to pull all the information you need into the 'back end' of your application, then use it as you need.

Answer (score -1):

Proplem in iphone must be active enable java in iphone safari settings